# "Error operating system not found" after replacing Windows with Parrot OS

Tags: boot, grub, parrotsec

I tried to install Parrot OS on a Windows PC. The OS installer ended without errors, but when starting the computer, I get "Error Systems Not Found". I deleted the partitions with Windows OS but left the partitions I used for storage to preserve my files (I have 2 HDDs, one 1 TB drive and one 500 GB drive). BIOS is in EFI mode, and the 500 GB drive is in GPA. I used "Boot Repair", but it is still not working.

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
Loopen 7:0 0 786.3M 1 loop /rofs
sda 8:0b0 931.5G disk
|-sdal 8:1 0 10G 0 part
|-sda2 8:2 0  8M part part
|-sda3 8:3 0 237 9G 0 part /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
|-sda5 8:5 0 683.6G 0 part
sdb    8:16 0 465.8G 0 disk
|-sdb1 8:17 0 8M 0 part
|-sdb2 8:18 0 9.8G 0 part
|-sdb3 8:19 0 435.8G 0 part
|-sdb4 8:20 0 20G 0 part /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4
|-sdb5 8:21 0 250M part
sdc    8:32 1 58.6G 0 disk /cdrom
|-sdc1 8:33 1 880M 0 part
|-sdc2 8:34 1 2.4M 0 part
zramo 252:0 0973.5M 0 disk [SWAP]
zram1 252:1 0 973.5M 0 disk [SWAP]
zram2 252:2 0 973.5M 0 disk [SWAP]
zram3 252:3 0 973.5M 0 disk [SWAP]
```